# Is there a C++ AMP equivalent to CUDA __ballot()?

Tags: gpu, c++-amp

CUDA defines a few warp voting functions. But I can't seem to find them in any C++ Amp documentation. I'm particularly interested in __ballot() because it would be insanely efficient for producing a mask that I need.

Does C++ Amp expose this functionality?

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions

Comment: Ditto for integer intrinsics:

[CUDA integer intrinsics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT_1g43c9c7d2b9ebf202ff1ef5769989be46)

Comment: Hmm, dusting off my old Amp C++ code.... It has become apparent that it's time to switch back to CUDA for the win!

Answer (score 2):

C++AMP doesn't have support for low level operations like this because it is written on top of DirectX. It is designed to target a number of different architectures so does not expose the specifics on a particular hardware platform.

The closest thing is the High Level Shader Language (HLSL) supports many intrinsic functions. C++ AMP exposes a subset 
of these within the concurrency::direct3dnamespace. They can be called only from amp-restricted code.

[direct3d namespace and HLSL intrinsics in C++ AMP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nativeconcurrency/2012/02/24/direct3d-namespace-and-hlsl-intrinsics-in-c-amp/)